# MONTHS_BETWEEN / NTH_VALUE

Tags: oracle, date, logic

I have some unique logic I am hoping to put into a query, rather than have to call out to a function.

In this application, I am looking at the last 4 reported quarters for a given ticker symbol.  The dates in the table are represented as YYYYMM as in this case:

```
201804,
201801,
201710,
201704
```

Now, it is possible there may be a quarter missing.  Maybe the company did not submit the quarterly report, or whatever.

So, what I am trying to do is see if there is a gap, or missing quarter:

```
201804,
201710,
201704,
201701
```

Here, 201801 is missing........I guess somehow I have to be able to compare the MONTHS_BETWEEN the current record date, and LEAD 1, or NTH_VALUE 1 date value, and see that the difference is 3 months.......for the last 4 records back (4 quarters).  If not, some record is missing, and I'll return a NULL value, which is what the application requires.

Any thoughts or unique logic?  Or would I need to code a function, and call out to it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just convert everything to date and use date manipulation with self joins

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f5d97/15)**

```
With cte as (
  SELECT "val", 
          TO_DATE("val", 'YYYYMM') as original
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT c1."val", c1.original, 
       c2.original as next_quarter,
       c3.original as previous_quarter
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.original = ADD_MONTHS(c2.original, -3)
LEFT JOIN cte c3
  ON c1.original = ADD_MONTHS(c3.original, 3)

ORDER BY c1."val"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|    val |             ORIGINAL |         NEXT_QUARTER |     PREVIOUS_QUARTER |
|--------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 201701 | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-04-01T00:00:00Z |               (null) |
| 201704 | 2017-04-01T00:00:00Z |               (null) | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 201710 | 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z |               (null) |               (null) |
| 201804 | 2018-04-01T00:00:00Z |               (null) |               (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calendar of quarters and outer join this data with your quarter data. This is how the query looks. The `p_start_year` is the year where your calendar starts and the `p_no_of_qtrs` counts the how many quarters show up in the calendar.

```
WITH
    mydata
    AS
        (SELECT '201804' AS quarter FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '201801' AS quarter FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '201710' AS quarter FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT '201704' AS quarter FROM DUAL),
    calendar
    AS
        (SELECT TO_CHAR (
                    ADD_MONTHS (
                        TO_DATE (:p_start_year || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        (LEVEL
                         - 1)
                        * 3
                    ),
                    'YYYYMM'
                )
                    AS quarter
         FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= :p_no_of_qtrs)
SELECT c.quarter, d.quarter AS status
FROM mydata d,
     calendar c
WHERE c.quarter = d.quarter(+)
ORDER BY c.quarter;
```

This is the result.

```
QUARTER | STATUS
201701  | 
201704  | 201704
201707  | 
201710  | 201710
201801  | 201801
201804  | 201804
201807  | 
201810  |
```

The missing quarters show up as NULLs.